# PFSense wildcard records for local hosts

Tags: pfsense, internal-dns, wildcard-subdomain

PFSense 2.3.2-RELEASE-p1

I have a local server running Apache. www.office.lan resolves to this server's IP.

I want to run multiple virtual hosts, each accessible by a unique subdomain, for example:

www_a.office.lan
www_b.office.lan
...

What I want to do is set up a wildcard like *.office.lan that defaults to this server if the host doesn't exist.

We have other servers on the network, such as nas.office.lan, and I don't want this to interfere with that.  If I need to use a different domain, such as dev.lan (ie. a.dev.lan, b.dev.lan, etc), that's OK too.

I've tried following suggestions, such as this one: https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Wildcard_Records_in_DNS_Forwarder/Resolver

I've added **address=/office.lan/192.168.1.7** to the Custom options box on the services_dnsmasq.php page, but when I try to ping test.office.lan, etc, it won't resolve.